# Remove ldap user

Tags: users, passwd, getent

Trying to remove a user with `userdel xyz` I get:

```
no crontab for xyz
userdel: cannot remove entry 'xyz' from /etc/passwd
```

So I executed `getent passwd xyz` and a record is returned. I thought that this is a ldap user so I followed the steps described [here](http://blog.zwiegnet.com/linux-server/remove-user-from-openldap-command-line/) but did not help. Any idea how to remove this user?

Comment: `ldapmodify` can be tricky to get right, or there might be permissions problems on LDAP; can you show exactly how you poked the LDAP server and what it said?